# Can I use the verb "Have" in the sentence "I don't have many things that I do at home"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm comfortable saying like this:

> 1. There are not many things that I do at home.
> 2. I don't do many things at home

Then, how about this?

> 3. I don't have many things that I do at home.

Is this possible to use?

Comment: Please use descriptive titles that actually explain your question. Generic titles don't let people know what you're asking.

Comment: There's no reason to keep your title so short - feel free to make it obvious what you're asking in your question title.

Comment: Oh I though I have to make it short if possible. Thank you~!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly fine. It's not really much different to if you were to say *I have lots of hobbies* --> *I have lots of hobbies that I do at home*.